# going back to previous screen in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am new to iPhone development, i have used view based application in which i have use navigation controller, after clicking row in custom table view, it shows a navigation controller with back button titled with the default title of previous screen.

But in detail view i have created a custom  back button and after clicking on that button i want to go back to the previous screen.

code to call custom button is:

```
  [backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and the code inside of btnClicked is:

```
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

but i am not going to the previous screen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have used a `navigationController` i guess you might have pushed the view onto the stack using `pushViewController: animated:` method. or perhaps even `presentModalViewcontroller: animated:`

If its the first case then in your custom back button method you should do

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If its the second case then it should do `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` but remember to dismiss from the object used to present it.

Comment: In case if i create another back button on navigation controller by following like [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubView:backBtn] then what should i use in the definition of backBtn Clicked method. I want that after going to previous screen that backbtn should not be displayed

Comment: Instead of adding subview to the navbar try to set the leftBarButtonItem of the navigation controller. Thats the better approach

Answer (score 1):

Use This:

```
    [self popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

And Make sure your Viewwillappear method must Be there.

Comment: In case if i create another back button on navigation controller by following like [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubView:backBtn] then what should i use in the definition of backBtn Clicked method

Comment: If you Want To Open/Push Another View You can Use [self.navigationController pushviewController:"Your View's Object Name" animated:yes];                                               And If you Want To Come Back From Any View Then use             [Self popViewControllerAnimated:Yes];

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
 [[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: +1 This is the answer, not sure why OP didn't selected this one.